# Overriding runat server JavaScript code at client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runatserver

Let's say I have a script in an ASP.NET page which runs at client side:

```
<script runat="server">function foo(){
//Some javascript code
}
</script>
```

My question is, can I(or anyone viewing this site) override this function foo from client side to:

```
function foo(){
 //my JavaScript code
}
```

such that it will run at server.

Comment: What kind of a setup do you have that is going to run javascript code on the server? I've never seen that before. C# or VB code goes in `runat="server"` blocks.

Comment: Client page has a javascript `function foo`,which has `runat='server'` ,just wanted to ask can the client override this foo function or not?

Comment: Have you successfully run a function defined in this way, on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, as that script (C#, I assume) will run at server, but why do you have that declared in the asp.net page?

Wouldn't it be better to have it in container (class for example)?
(could be a code-behind file for classic ASP.NET WebForms, in a Model or Controller for MVC)

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh(v=vs.100).ASPX

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `runat="server"` simply instructs ASP.NET to pre-parse that element (and its child elements if any) on the server, before returning the result to the client browser.

Once you reach there (the client browser):

1. You can override the result (e.g. using your own client-side function)
2. You can't parse your own code on the server again.

Hope this makes sense.

P.S. I know it is a question from 2016